# Hibernate: cannot cascading delete unidirectional parent of children

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

When deleting the parent of children (in a 1 to many unidirectional relation) I keep on getting these errors. 
When I delete the children first, everything works OK.

I don't need/want a bi-directional relationship.

This is the parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "datagroup")
public class DataGroup implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "group_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int         group_id;
    private String      name;

    @OneToMany( targetEntity=DataGroupItem.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name="group_id")
    private List<DataGroupItem> dataGroupItems = new ArrayList<>( 0);
    ... setters and getters
}
```

And this is the child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "datagroupitems")
public class DataGroupItem implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "item_id", nullable = false)
    private int item_id;
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "group_id", nullable = false)
    private int group_id = 0; // only for (un)delete
    ... getters and setters
}
```

When deleting the parent in a Controller I do:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/learner/groups")
public class LearnerSyncServices {
    @Autowired
    private IDataGroupRepository dataGroupRepository;
    @Autowired
    private IDataGroupItemRepository dataGroupItemRepository;
    ... 

    @RequestMapping( method= RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable String id) {
        try {
            int idx = Integer.parseInt( id);
            dataGroupRepository.delete( idx);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error( "Cannot delete " + id + "  " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

As JPA version I have: Spring boot version 4.1.3.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Deleting the group with at least 1 child gives the following messages:

```
.. WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
.. ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Column 'group_id' cannot be null
.. INFO  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
.. ERROR nl.deholtmans.tjm1706.learner.LearnerSyncServices - Cannot delete 101  could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Comment: The reference to the group is `nullable=false`. You either need to set a new reference for every child or use cascading to delete every child as well (if that's desired).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on 'nullable=false" and on both of your options? Maybe it is best to put it in an answer (and not a comment).
Preferred is the cascading delete: delete the group and all of it's children

Comment: have you tried CascadeType DELETE_ORPHAN?

Comment: Oh, its depracted, now its @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)

Comment: Nothing changed, still an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting the `DataGroup`, hibernate first tries to issue the SQL statement that will delete the parent, and then proceeds to issue statements that remove the children.

When deleting the parent, the foreign key in the `datagroupitems` table must be set to `NULL` to maintain db consistency (at that point, it is not obvious to the db that children rows are going to be deleted as well). However, it cannot be set to `NULL` because you specifically forbade it in your schema definition.

Hibernate simply does not know it should delete children first, parent last. You can fix this by allowing the `group_id` column to be nullable.

EDIT If you're not using 'hbm2ddl.auto/javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action', do not forget to recreate/manually update your db schema. The `NOT NULL` constraint needs to be dropped from the database for this solution to work.

Comment: I get the same error when I set in the child to this: 
@Column(name = "group_id") 
private int group_id = 0; 
OR: @Column(name = "group_id", nullable = true).

Comment: I understand that you recreated your schema after performing the changes?

Comment: Also, could you explain why you need the `group_id` column mapped in `DataGroupItem ` in the first place? You claimed you didn't need a bi-directional relationship. I'd try to remove the mapping or make it `updatable=false` to see if the problem goes away

Comment: please elaborate on your comment 'recreated your schema'. 
I don't want a reference in the child to the parent. So, I don't want to have a property 'DataGroup parentDataGroup' in the child (DataGroupItem).

Comment: ANd ... updatable=false won't allow me adding/removing more children? 
When I remove the relation ... the retrieving the parent won't retrieve the children too.

Comment: By `recreated your schema`, I mean are you sure the `CONSTRAINT group_id NOT NULL` has been dropped after you changed `nullable=false` to `nullable=true`? Do you have `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` defined in your `persistence.xml`, for example? If you're getting the **exact same** error, then it seems the `NOT NULL` constraint hasn't been dropped. Try removing it manually

Comment: Also, If you don't want a reference in the child to the parent, why do you need the `group_id` field in the `DataGroupItem` at all? It seems you want to eat the cake and have it, too

Comment: ah ... thank you. Yes, recreating the schema solved the issue. Now the constrained was removed in the schema as well.
>>> Please add your 'recreate schema' also to your answer. Then I will mark it as solved.

Comment: Can you explain why in this relationship hibernate first tries to null out the FK, delete the parent, and then finally the child? If the parent has the list of children mapped right on the entity, why couldn't it know to delete the children first? When mapped as a bidirectional relationship, it seems to delete the children first.

Comment: TBH I don't know the answer to that question, that's just the way Hibernate folks implemented it. Perhaps it has something to do with failing fast when there's some other reason the parent cannot be deleted, but that's just a guess